# Долгий ответ сервера,использую curl на клиенте

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

Использую OC Ubuntu 18.04, apache2.0, mysql,php 7.2
На клиенте использую curl для связи с выделенным сервером на Ubuntu.
Задача севера обрабатывать и вернуть данные.
Если загрузить ссылку к примеру http://mysqte/data.php;
ТО это займет для получения данных 0,3 сек. Отлично,меня это устраивает.
Но работать надо через curl и выводить данные в нужные таблицы.

```
    $f="http://mysite/data.php";
    $headers = httpGetAllHeaders();
    $ch=curl_init($f);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$f);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $i=curl_exec($ch);
```

Данные на клиенте используя curl я получаю спустя от 2,5 до 4 секунд.
Смотрел скорость работы скрипта, 0,1 секунда,там его не много.

```
[content_type] => text / html; charset = UTF-8 
[http_code] => 200 
[header_size] => 147 
[request_size] => 997 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 2.047 
[namelookup_time] => 0 
[connect_time] => 0,047 
[pretransfer_time] => 0,047
 [size_upload] = > 0 
[size_download] => 3 
[speed_download] => 1 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => 3
 [upload_content_length] => -1 
[starttransfer_time] => 2.047 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[certinfo] => Array ()
```

Я не пойму в чем причина?
Почему так долго приходиться ждать ответа?
Как это можно решить?
Решил спросить, кучу мануал по настройке apache применил,проблема в том,после пару мануал,ничего не помогло и пришлось переустанавливать сервер.

Comment: Я вот тоже не пойму вы работаете со своим сайтом?

Comment: Сервер и клиент мои

Comment: жесть, а зачем тогда курл?

Comment: После настройки клиента, будут пользоваться другие  с таким временем, стресоустойчевые.

Comment: Вы же хотите отправлять и принимать, `php://input` как-раз после отправки прочитает сервер, отправит ответ клиенту, на клиенте принять и расставить по местам или выполнить перебор. Получается как: `Client<->Server and Server<->Client`.

Comment: Именно так и работает.

Comment: Зачем тогда курл?

Comment: Что бы много клиентов обращались к серверу

Comment: Прочитайте про клиент серверные приложения. И все станет ясно и никакого курла там не нужно.

Comment: Буду благодарен, если скинешь ссылку.